# Centering my Logo Div

Tags: html, css

I have tried every possible method to center my logo div but no luck. I even ended up going back to old school align="center" but no luck.

Please help - http://rezaee.me/kel/

Cheers

Comment: when position: fixed is removed, the header breaks

Comment: Looks centered to me.  Did you fix it?  If so, please mark the answer that helped you fix it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `position: fixed` from your `#logo` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `position: fixed;` from your CSS for `#logo`.

Answer (score 1):

don't make its position: fixed

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `position:fixed` and it'll be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think removing position fixed is enough.  Remove all css and try this

Make your logo an img tag instead of a background, then use margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%; width: (width of img);